# How $ y(x,t) = A.Cos(k.x - \omega .t + \Phi ) $ is one dimensional wave?

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

$$ y(x,t) = A . Cos(k.x - \omega .t + \Phi ) $$

How the above equation is one-dimensional wave. Where at every value of $' x ' $ we get value of $ ' y ' $ where $ ' t ' $ is time. It should be two dimensional.

Comment: Dear @PM2Ring it is 1-D as a mathematical model? or how many dimensional .wave it is , because this wave equation shows the pattern of transverse wave and many examples are related to this. Why it is called one-Dimensional wave.

Comment: $y$ is in general *not* a spatial coordinate like $x$. It is “whatever quantity is waving”. Only *sometimes* is the thing that is waving the displacement in a transverse direction, as for a vibrating string. When it is temperature or pressure or whatever it is not a coordinate.